# How should I reconcile dot-underscore files after a manual backup?

Tags: macos, filesystem, hfs+

I recently had to (hurriedly) back up data on an older Macbook before migrating it to a new one. Since all I had at my disposal was a large FAT32 formatted drive, I used that and a manual copy. I've since used `rsync` to put it back on a (non-journaled) HFS+ drive (under Ubuntu).

Now most of the files have a corresponding `._` file alongside them. I understand that this is how OS X stores extended attributes and other information on non-HFS+ filesystems. So my question is: now that I have these files back on a HFS+ filesystem, how can I reconcile the information in the `._` files? That is, since the data in those files can now be stored in the HFS+ metadata for each file, how do I put it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the files using Finder. It seems Finder can reconcile these when copying from a partition type that doesn't support extended metadata to a partition type that does, reversing it's procedure for doing the reverse and creating the dotfiles.

Comment: Seems reasonable. I'll try it out soon.

Comment: "…  from a partition type that doesn't support extended metadata …"; the ._ files are already on HFS Plus.

Comment: @Graham Yes, but copied with rsync which doesn't merge the dotfiles. I meant copying them from the original FAT32 partition to the HFS+ with Finder.

Comment: Not only Finder. Utilities such as [ditto(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html) will preserve resource forks, HFS metadata, extended attributes and ACLs.

Answer (score 9):

### dot_clean

[dot_clean(1) Mac OS X Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dot_clean.1.html)

Apple's description:

> `For each dir, dot_clean recursively merges all ._* files with their
>   corresponding native files according to the rules specified with the
>   given arguments.  By default, if there is an attribute on the native
>   file that is also present in the ._ file, the most recent attribute
>   will be used.`
>
> `If no operands are given, a usage message is output.  If more than one
>   directory is given, directories are merged in the order in which they
>   are specified.`

Proceed with caution. Whilst the man page lists no known bugs, it is possible to lose data through careless use of the command.

Comment: I've always thought dot_clean simply cleaned the dotfiles rather than merging them; this is the way to go, +1

Comment: When I last checked, long ago, there was no file system capability check. So, for example, applying a `dot_clean` command to any part of an MS-DOS FAT32 volume would silently lose (be unable to merge) the content of `._` files in that part of the volume. Square peg, round hole ;)